# How to set MAX_ATTEMPTS from code to Google Cloud Task?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-tasks

How to set `MAX_ATTEMPT` of the tasks in google cloud queue in code?

When I create new task, I want to set how many repetitions of a given task should be, can I do it from the code below?

I have google cloud queue like here:

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

async function createHttpTask() {
  const project = 'my-project-id';
  const queue = 'my-queue';
  const location = 'us-central1';
  const url = 'https://example.com/taskhandler';
  const payload = 'Hello, World!';
  const inSeconds = 180;

  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
    },
  };

  if (payload) {
    task.httpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
  }

  console.log('Sending task:');
  console.log(task);
  const request = {parent: parent, task: task};
  await client.createTask(request);
}
createHttpTask();
```

From the Google Cloud Documentation i see that I can do it from the console, for the whole queue - https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#retry , but I want to set this dynamically for the tasks

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.  You can not set retry parameters on individual tasks.  I make this claim by looking at this document:

[REST Resource: projects.locations.queues](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues#Queue)

which is the REST API for creating task queues.  In there, under the documentation for `retryConfig` we read:

> For tasks created using Cloud Tasks: the queue-level retry settings apply to all tasks in the queue that were created using Cloud Tasks. Retry settings cannot be set on individual tasks.

Comment: So you can create a queue per tasks handling behavior, and push the task in the correct queue.